# Error while Authenticating sharepoint site with Azure AD users using Azure Access Control Namespace

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-acs

I have a Sharepoint site running on Azure virtual Machine.
Now i want to authenticate my sharepoint site with Azure AD users.

For this i have followed below link, but getting error after login.

[Using Microsoft Azure Active Directory for SharePoint 2013 authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn635311.aspx)

I have implemented as given on reference link, but still facing error.
When i access my url from browser, it will ask me through which you want to logon.

[image]

Then on selection of ACS Provider, it will redirect me to office365 login.
After i submit my credentials, it will redirect me to

https://testvm.cloudapp.net/_trust/

and got error. So i checked in sharepoint log and found below error.

Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri urn:sharepoint:spvms.

SPAudienceValidator: Audience uri 'urn:sharepoint:spvms is not valid for the context.

Getting Error Message for Exception Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException: The Audience URI could not be validated.

SPSaml11SecurityTokenHandler: Audience validation failed for request 'https://testvm.cloudapp.net/_trust/' with the following audience URIs: 'urn:sharepoint:spvms', .

Application error when access /_trust/, Error=The Audience URI could not be validated.
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSaml11SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateConditions(SamlConditions conditions, Boolean enforceAudienceRestriction)
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.TokenReceiver.AuthenticateToken(SecurityToken token, Boolean ensureBearerToken, String endpointUri)
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequest request)
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Not yet, still same error

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the authentication to Azure AD is working and the redirect to SharePoint is working properly. Use Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer and verify the realm... it looks like the realm being sent from Azure ACS does not match the realm you used in PowerShell.

Comment: where should i use Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer. Should i run it on Azure VM?

Comment: On the same server that SharePoint is running, unless you have set up PowerShell remoting.

Answer (score 0):

I got a working solution for that. The thing is you shouldn't use `New-MsolServicePrincipal` to connect Azure AD and ACS.

Instead you add your ACS as an App to Azure Id

[image]

Then view its endpoints and copy link FEDERATION METADATA DOCUMENT

[image]

Paste copied link in URL field of your Identity provider in ACS

[image]

NOTE: If you used `New-MsolServicePrincipal` you will need to use `Remove-MsolServicePrincipal`. Otherwise Azure won't let you register an app with the same url.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for your answer. I will check this and let you know the result